# Netsuite custom formula - max of 2 numbers?

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite, how do I take the max of two numbers/values in a custom formula? Currently the following is throwing an error: max({shippingcost},{custbody3})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

providing custbody3 is numeric use `GREATEST({shippingcost},{custbody3})`

see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php

Usual note here: Netsuite uses PL/SQL functions in formulas. Many more than are shown in the function list can be used.

Comment: Thanks! Since I didn't know the syntax I solved it a different way. I created a work flow that split on shippingcost > custbody3 and set the value to shippingcost in one case and custbody3 in the other. Basically created my own max function. I'm sure this is a bit faster execution wise.